# How to display math results with formular expression in angular17?

Tags: angular, mathjax, katex

Similar to MathCAD I like to display in the HTML template the used formular with the used values and the result well formated in math notation.

eg. Mt= F*L/4, in the the html:

```
;
<p…>The Text is allways static </p…>
     <…>{{Mt}}=…{{F}}x{{L}}…/4<…>
<p…> some added static text</p…>
```

there all varialbles are allready calculated and *two way binded* with the related component.

That means, it is not needed that a user will create a math expression, only plain input values will calculated and results will be displayed upon the static formular. Therefore I am looking for a lightweight solution and how to implement into angular 17.

Mathjax full import seems to be oversized for this requirement,